# Can I modify a private static array with a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, static

I have a class called cardNames. Every new game I will create a new instance of cardNames which would correspond to the current cards being used. I would prefer to have them as static so I won't have to send a copy of the cardNames object around.

Is this legal?

```
public class cardNames 
{
    private static String[] characters;
    private static String[] weapons;
    private static String[] rooms;
    private int totalCards;

    public cardNames(String[] theCharacters, String[] theWeapons, String[] theRooms)
    {
        characters = Arrays.copyOf(theCharacters, theCharacters.length);
        weapons = Arrays.copyOf(theWeapons, theWeapons.length);
        rooms = Arrays.copyOf(theRooms,  theRooms.length);
        totalCards = characters.length + weapons.length + rooms.length;
    }

    public static String[] getCharacters()
    {
        return Arrays.copyOf(characters, characters.length);
    }
```

Would I have a new set of characters, weapons, and rooms after I create a new cardName object?

Comment: Your code should _run_, but keep in mind that your class level arrays are static, meaning that there is only one copy of them associated with the class itself.  All instances would share that same static state.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Does that mean that I would have a new set of arrays replacing the previous ones I had after I create a new cardNames object? Can I do that even if I call the constructor with arrays of different length than the previous ones?

Comment: If you just remove `static` from the top level array definitions, they would become instance variables, and then every time your constructor gets called, the input arrays would be copied over to the instance arrays.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I would have to carry around a cardNames object around which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Well if that state makes sense as static, class level, state, then keep your code as is.